# Form on my website submitting to google forms with upload feature

Tags: javascript, html, upload, google-forms

I built a form on a site that submits to google forms by changing the action attribute of the form and the name attribute of my inputs like this:

```
<input id="email" name="entry.8000968736" required="" type="text" />
```

I used fake numbers there. I have done this in the past but now am trying to allow users to upload a file. for the upload feature I copied the whole div that held the uploader and the input with the action to catch the scripts I needed. I also copy and pasted the head of the source for the same reason:

```
<div jsname="kTlJSc" class="freebirdFormviewerViewItemsFileuploadChipList" 
role="list" aria-label="Selected files"></div>
<div role="button" class="quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonEl 
quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonFlat quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonFlatColored 
quantumWizButtonPaperbutton2El2 freebirdFormviewerViewItemsFileuploadAddButton 
 button-left-align" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; 
 mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; 
mouseleave:JywGue;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; 
touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); 
touchcancel:JMtRjd;focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;" jsshadow 
jsname="mWZCyf" aria-label="Add file" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-
describedby="i35 i.desc.1278963519 i.err.1278963519 i.req.1278963519">
<div class="quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd">
</div>
<div class="quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonFocusOverlay exportOverlay"></div>
    <content class="quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonContent">
        <span class="quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonLabel exportLabel">Add 
file</span>
    </content>
</div>
<div id="i.req.1278963519" class="screenreaderOnly"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="entry.1582391431" jsname="L9xHkb" disabled>
```

When I load the page the rest of the form works except this portion. It looks and acts like a link until you click and nothing happens. I'm building this on wordpress if it helps to know and I also already tried using a window with an active google login and one without.

Comment: Ask only one question at a time.  Type in an actual MVE, **no photos of code**. Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask a Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or whatever you have done or tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Hey SherylHohman. Sorry. I'm kinda new to stack overflow. I didn't realize there were rules. Should I start a new question or edit this one?

Comment: NP, that's why SO has reviewers.  Either way.  If you can edit this question to adhere to SO guidelines, then go for it !!  And if you need to post a second or third question additionally, do that as well. Best of Luck in finding your answers.